# How to limit the numbers of objects displayed?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

How to limit results displaying via Mongoose ? I'd like to display only the first 5 objects of my results array, contained in the Carauction Schema:

```
router.get('/app/:cars_getroute', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
Promise.all([Car.findOne({ cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute }), Carauction.findOne({ cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute }), Carauctionstats.findOne({cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute})])
    .then(result => {
        const [cars, carauctions, carauctionstats] = result;

        if (User.isCharged = true) {
            res.render('app/fichecar', {
                results: carauctions.results,
        })...
```

My schema:

```
const CarauctionSchema = new Schema({
    objectID: {
        type: Number
    },
    cars_getroute: {
        type: String
    },
    gm_url: {
        type: String
    },
    "results": {
        type: [{
            marque: {
                type: String
            },
            model: {
                type: String
            }...}]
    }
```

I'd like to limit to 10 results object. I tried with Carauction.find(carauctions.results).limit(10) but it doesn't work.

Then I render the results items with handlebars:

```
{{#each results as |auction|}}

                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="{{auction.auction_url}}" class="results__box--hover">
                        <div class="results__container--box">
                            <div class="results__container--img">
                                <img src="{{auction.image_urls}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="results__container--left">
                                <div class="results__container--model">
                                    <span>{{auction.model_year}} {{auction.marque}} {{auction.model}}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="results__container--auction">
                                    <span class="results__auction_house">{{auction.auction_house}}</span>
                                    <span>{{auction.auction_country}}</span>
                                    <span class="results__auction_date">{{auction.auction_date}}</span>


            {{/each}}
```

Comment: `if(User.isCharged = true) {` isn't doing what you expect it to. You should change it to: `if(User.isCharged == true) {` or `if(User.isCharged) {`

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the results using `carauctions.results.slice(0,10)`.  This will output up to 10 items, but will not cause problems if there are less.

Comment: Thanks ! It doesn't work (500 error) because I forgot to say that I display each result in HTML with handlebars. I'm not sure that's the cause but I edited my question.

Comment: Can you provide the console output of the HTTP 500?

Comment: Ok, your solution is good for my main question but your precision about the isCharge = true is not. It was the error. Thank you very much !

Comment: `isCharge = true` is an assignment.  It changes the value to `true` rather than doing a comparison against `true`.